# How to catch mount events on Linux?

Tags: mount, python, events

I want to somehow get notified if a mount or unmount occurs for a USB drive.

At the moment I use udev and then wait for x seconds for a new entry in /proc/mounts. This works ok if the mounting is automatic. However this won't work if the user unmounts/mounts the device manually.

Is there a way to catch those events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If polling is okay you could look at the time on `mtab`:

```
import time, os
last = None
current = None

for x in range(0,60):
    if last == current:
        current = os.stat('/etc/mtab').st_mtime
        print('Current Updated: ', current)
        print('No Changes...')
    else:
        last = current
        print('Last Updated: ',last)
        print('Something was mounted or unmounted')
    time.sleep(1)
```

You could also use `filecmp` or `difflib` to see if there are any changes, and parse what kind of changes occurred if you go with this route.

Comment: I am not sure why the other user deleted their answer. They brought up a really good point with looking at `/proc/mounts` and `/proc/self/mounts` ... `mtab` is a symobolic link and might not be as up to date, but more software friendly, whereas `/proc/mounts` will have everything, or as far as I understand it.

Comment: Yes, as kernel devs said when they [removed KOBJ_MOUNT & KOBJ_UNMOUNT from kernel uevents](https://lkml.org/lkml/2007/4/6/37), `/proc/mounts` is the way to go. I would definitely not rely on `mtime` as it is constantly updated even if nothing is mounted/unmounted (run `stat -c %Y /proc/mounts` in terminal, wait a few seconds, run it again). See also the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5070801/1601027).

Comment: A lot of distributions have `/etc/mtab` as a symbolic link to `/proc/mounts`. I don't know what determines the mtime of `/proc/mounts`, but in many cases it's the current date. The content read from `/proc/mounts` is generated on the fly, it isn't rebuilt each time the data would change, so there's no reason why the mtime of `/proc/mounts` would be significant.